# Alternative to CSS transform origin

Tags: css, mpdf

I am using mPDF which ignores the following CSS:

```
-webkit-transform-origin: top left;
-moz-transform-origin: top left;
-o-transform-origin: top left;
-ms-transform-origin: top left;
```

This will render my html file in the browser fine but when the pdf is created each div in my pdf document is on a single line down the entire page.

Every div in the html document has an absolute position with its Left and Top property set with approximate px for its position in the document.

Example :

```
#tf_1{left:34px;top:161px;}
#tg_1{left:239px;top:161px;}
#th_1{left:239px;top:126px;}
#ti_1{left:45px;top:394px;}
```

Can anyone help with a possible alternative?

Comment: The snippet of CSS you provided is not helpful. What HTML and CSS are you using on your website? What have you done to try and resolve this? Have you read through the documentation about table layouts? [Here](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=319) and [here](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=77)

Comment: @crazymatt actually I thought it was pretty clear. I am not using tables. Each and every div has its absolute position set from the relative positioned div they all reside in. Since mpdf ignores the transform-orgin property the divs ignore their default position. So, instead of rendering the divs with a visual appearance of an inline block, it just makes each div appear as there is a line break after each one. In html the css is fine. In the pdf it is incorrect. I tried setting the class for all of the divs to inline as well as inline-block, also tried float:left. Nothing changed.

Comment: Hmm based on what I read in the documentation it seems that they push for people to use Tables for the layout. It mentions that they support the float property so if you want a work around that might be the way to go. Another method i was thinking of was using display:table-cell but they dont mention that in the doc and so its probably not supported.